# Как записывать html теги в переменные миксина в Jade(Pug)

Tags: переменные, jade, mixins, pug

Я новичок в Jade(Pug).Ещё не понимаю таких тонкостей.

Имеем код:

```
mixin label(labelValue)
    label= labelValue
```

В большинстве случаев в миксин записываются простой текст, но иногда туда нужно записать ссылку. 
Как это можно сделать?

UPD: весь mixin

```
mixin skill(skillTitle, labelValue, status)
if status === 'checked'
    input.skills__input(
        class='skills__input_#{skillTitle}'
        id='#{skillTitle}'
        type='checkbox'
        name='#{skillTitle}'
        checked
    )
else
    input.skills__input(
        class='skills__input_#{skillTitle}'
        id='#{skillTitle}'
        type='checkbox'
        name='#{skillTitle}'
    )

label.skills__label(
    class='skills__label_#{skillTitle}'
    for='#{skillTitle}'
)= labelValue
```

Когда я просто записываю атрибуты, всё в порядке

```
+skill('jade','Pug (Jade)')
```

Из кода выше я получаю в HTML:

```
<input id="jade" type="checkbox" name="jade" class="skills__input skills__input_jade">
<label for="jade" class="skills__label skills__label_jade">Pug (Jade)</label>
```

Я хочу для некоторых label сделать ссылки, что-то вроде:

```
+skill('jade',<a href="#">'Pug (Jade)'</a>)
```

И получить из этого:

```
<input id="jade" type="checkbox" name="jade" class="skills__input skills__input_jade">
<label for="jade" class="skills__label skills__label_jade"><a href="#">Pug (Jade)</a></label>
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Можете показать из чего и какой результат хотите получить?

Comment: Обновил тред, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

```html
mixin label(labelValue)
    label !{labelValue}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]